# Python tkinter treeview insert from a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tkinter, treeview

Do you know if there is another way than using a 'for' loop to feed the tkinter treeview widget from a list, because the loading time is relatively long with this instruction?

Thanks for your answers!

```
my_list = []
for i in range(1, 1_000_001):
    my_list.append(i)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')

my_treeview = ttk.Treeview(root)

my_treeview['columns'] = 'Données'
for column in my_treeview['columns']:
    my_treeview.heading(column, text=column)

for item in my_list:
    my_treeview.insert('', 'end', values=item)

my_treeview.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Loading time: about 5 seconds

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say hello!

Comment: Inserting million rows in about 5 seconds is not that bad.  `Treeview` does not have function to insert rows in one shot because it need to return the row ID in each insertion.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but in reality the files I work on can contain more than 18 million cells, and there the reading time is well over 5 seconds

Comment: Then you better use *Paging* concept, i.e. only show certain records (for example 20 records per page) at a time.  Then you just need to clear the treeview and insert the required records into the treeview whenever *page* is changed.

Comment: @acw1668 You have found the solution which is by principle not computerized: a human cannot read 1 million lines (except in exceptional cases), pagination is indeed the best solution, thank you very much!